# $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} f(a_n)=0$ and also $\underset{x \to 0}{\lim} f(x)=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need the simple example of non constant function $f(x)$and a sequence $a_n$ that tends to zero (and all its members are not equal to zero) , that fulfills the following conditions :

1.$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} f(a_n)=0$  and also $\underset{x \to 0}{\lim} f(x)=1$

2.$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} f(a_n)=0$  and also $\underset{x \to 0}{\lim} f(x)=0$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. is impossible.${}$

Comment: I think you're asking for two different examples here (1 and 2), right?

Comment: To elaborate on @AndresCaicedo's comment, the limit of a function $f$ as the argument tends to $0$ is only defined if for _any_ sequence $a_n$ tending to zero (but never equal to zero), $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(a_n)$ is the same. Condition 1 violates this.

Answer (score 1):

For (2) you can take the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$ and the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$